# Django app discovery issue in settings file. How to solve?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-settings

I am building a project using django 1.7.8

To make different setting file for local and production environment i have made changes to settings file .

i have added local_settings.py and production_settings.py which are exact copy of another file called settings_template.py (base of all setting variables)

Thus my **settings.py** file looks like this :

```
####################################################################################################
#1) Never commit this file
#2) use local_settings.py for local use
#3) commit settings.template if you want to commit any addition or removal in actual settings which
# should reflect on production as well . 
###################################################################################################

# lowest priority of base template for setting , import it first , then local settings can override its values
# LOWEST PRIORITY
try:
    from settings_template import *
except ImportError as e:
    pass


# if local or development version of settings.py file is present use it 
# MID PRIORITY
try:
    from local_settings import *
except ImportError as e:
    pass

# if production version of settings.py file is present use it | HIGHEST PRIORITY
# HIGHEST PRIORITY
try:
    from production_settings import *
except ImportError as e:
    pass
```

and my **settings_template.py** file looks like :

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os


MY_SITE_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000"

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'j2x^8(w64ayq@jr5bc5gfdgdfgfdgfdgdfgdfgfdgfg3+z7'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',

    # for all auth 
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',

    # our application apps
    'users',
    'app_setings',
    'customer_service', 
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'testproject.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'testproject.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#databases

#DATABASES = {
#    'default': {
#        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
#        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
#    }
#}

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'testproject',                      
        'USER': 'django',
        'PASSWORD': 'test',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

# use utc time all over 
#USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR + "/static/media/uploads/"

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = MY_SITE_URL + '/static/media/'

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"

#STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR + '/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# added for all auth 
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)


TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.core.context_processors.tz',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'allauth.account.context_processors.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount',
)

SITE_ID = 1
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'


######### django all auth #########################################################
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'facebook': {
        'SCOPE': ['email'],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {'auth_type': 'reauthenticate'},
        'METHOD': 'oauth2',
        'VERIFIED_EMAIL': False
    }
}
###################################################################################


################ Custom all auth settings ################################
SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "none"
###################################################################################


###################################################################################
# custom variables for social AUTH 
# store social app ID here 
FACEBOOK_WEB_ID = 1
FACEBOOK_MOB_ID = 1
GOOGLE_WEB_ID = 3
GOOGLE_MOB_ID = 4
###################################################################################


# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    #    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)



# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    #     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)


TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)
```

I added an app called **'users'** earlier which is easily visible in django admin panel as well after registering it models.

Now when i am trying to add 2 new apps called **'customer_service'** , **'app_settings'** and run command :

```
python manage.py makemigrations customer_service
```

i am getting this error in terminal :

```
App 'customer_service' could not be found. Is it in INSTALLED_APPS?
```

**So when i copied the whole content of settings_template.py into settings.py file and run makemigrations it worked**

and then after making migrations i again reverted back settings.py as displayed above and code works fine .

**But when i added models of customer_service and app_settings app in their respective admin.py files and started the server , i was not able to see their models in django admin panel**

and when i again copied all content of settings_template.py into settings.py file and restarted the server **it worked** and i can see all models in django admin .

---

> How can i solve this ? I want to have a basic setup for local and
>   production but it should work normally as well .. like i am able to
>   use and create and migrate django apps smoothly .

---

---

Edit : I have not placed local_settings.py or production_settings.py files in the settings folders in above case . So they will not be considered and  only settings_template have any impact here.

Answer (score 1):

You are importing `*` from `local_settings` and `production_settings` after you imported from `settings_template`. So your `INSTALLED_APPS` is getting overwritten somewhere.

The idea about environment separation is that you put the common settings in one file (in your case `settings_template`). And then only add the environment specific settings in `local_settings` and `production_settings`.

Also, you probably don't want to import both production and local settings directly into the settings. You should import from local file when you're in local environment and from production file when in production environment.

It's a good practice to put everything in `settings.py` and then import from either local or production instead of creating 3 files like you did.

Comment: i have added more info in Edit , i have placed only settings_template.py file . There is no local or production file there for now .

Answer (score 0):

One of the most recommended way to do this is as follow:

having your setting directory:

```
my_project/
|-- my_app/
|-- my_project/
|   |-- settings/
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- base.py
|   |   |-- development.py
|   |   |-- production.py
|   |-- urls.py
|   |-- wsgi.py
|-- manage.py
```

- **base.py** contains basically the same content of the default file **settings.py**.
- **development.py** contains basically

  `from .base import *
  DEBUG = True`
- **production.py** contains basically

  `from .base import *
  DEBUG = False`

then based on your needs, you add in `base.py` for global settings and in the `development.py` for local settings etc.

- But the question now is how to say to django which settings file you wish to use:

  1. the easiest way:

     `python manage.py runserver --settings=my_project.settings.development`
  2. the other way, you need to set an environment variable in your shell:

     `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=my_project.settings.development`

     then simply `python manage.py runserver`

**Tip**: If you choose the second method, so for permanent config either you add 
`export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=my_project.settings.development` to your `.bashrc` file or if your are using a virtual environement (`virtualenvwrapper`) you can make the following config:

edit **virtual_environemt_path/bin/postactivate**

add this line:  `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=my_project.settings.development`

edit **virtual_environemt_path/bin/predeactivate**

add this line: `unset DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`